# Orbits of solution lie in level sets

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $F:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function on an open set $X\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to find an autonomous differential equation $y'=f(y)$ on $X$ such that the orbits of its solution lie in the level sets of $F$.

My idea was that this would mean that $(F'\circ y)\cdot y'=(F\circ y)'=0$, but this doesn't really look autonomous to me. What would be the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** since solutions of your system $y' = f(y)$ lie in the level sets of $F(y)$, it's very easy to show that $\nabla F \cdot f(y) \equiv 0$ in the whole $X$. Using that $F(y)$ and its $\nabla F =\left (\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \right)$ are known, can you come up with any vector field that is everywhere orthogonal to $\nabla F$?

> For example, $f(y) = \left ( \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}, -  \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)$.